# Name for "orthogonal eigenvalues" of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

It seems that any $n\times n$ matrix $A$ can be written like $Q\Lambda O^T$ for orthogonal matrices $Q,O$ and diagonal matrix $\Lambda$. I want to reference the values $\lambda_1\ldots \lambda_n$ in my project, and was wondering if they have an existing name. They seem pretty fundamental to the structure of square matrices, and I'm sure other people have come across them. They are also the square roots of the eigenvalues of $A^T A$ or $AA^T$.

I'm planning on calling them "orthogonal eigenvalues" or "orthogonal stresses" or something like that, but it would be nice to know if they already have a name.

Comment: Singular values.

Comment: And I think it's better to use different letters to denote these matrices. $Q$ and $O$ look too similar, which greatly confused me at first.

Comment: You might want to read about [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) which is what you are describing (for real matrices).